# Looking for a tutorial or document for creating FAQ list in sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

Is there a document or tutorial where i can find how to create a  custom widget 
 for table of contents having content link and content section (clicking each content link takes you to the corresponding section ). 
Having both (table of contents and its section) in one widget would be great.

Thanks

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically mentions this sort of question as being off-topic here. Your experiences at this site will be greatly improved if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages in order to understand what is (and is not) proper to ask about here before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the built-in Lists in Sitefinity.

Docs: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/list-widget-mvc

You can use either Expandable List or Anchor List option to achieve your goal.